# how to center print()'d raphael text in a space

Tags: javascript, raphael, vector-graphics, typography

i am curious as to the proper way to either figure required rendering space for print()'d text or how to have raphael render text from the center outward, as

```
var an = Raphael("about-navlink", 69, 22), fonts = [0, an.getFont("arialbold")], about_navlink = an.print(0, 10, "about.", fonts[1], 22).attr({fill: "#000000"});
```

makes text originate from the left. i would like to make the parts of this code dynamic with php or pick a static width within which to center and forego the calculation. i have looked throughout raphael's documentation and i do not find anything in the print() reference that discusses text alignment. any help would be greatly appreciated. thanks!

Comment: anything? left justification is not a problem. but print() only seems to justify from that direction...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Raphael has rendered the path corresponding to your text, let's say `printed`:

- use `Raphael.pathBBox(printed.attr('path'))` ([doc](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Raphael.pathBBox)), compute the negative offset (-width/2 and -height/2)
- create a matrix with `var m = Raphael.matrix()` that you translate with your offset (`m.translate(left, top)`) or put offset values directly in the matrix constructor arguments (5th and 6th args for left and top)
- then you have two ways to apply it:

  1. use `Raphael.mapPath` to definitely apply the matrix (it computes a path string you have to set with:

     ```
     printed.attr(
         'path',
         Raphael.mapPath(printed.attr('path'), m)
     );
     ```
  2. or use it like a simple transform:

     ```
     printed.transform(
         m.toTransformString()
     );
     ```

     If there were other transforms on this element, use

     ```
     '...' + m.toTransformString()
     ```

     to make your transform happening before existing ones, and

     ```
     m.toTransformString() + '...'
     ```

     to make your transform happening after.

Comment: ok, this is starting to make sense... i have been totally immersed in a project and have put off reading this until i could actually take a moment from the crunch! thank you for the solution! it's going to a good cause!